# Format a number to include commas

Tags: python, formatting

This is my attempt to format a number and put commas where appropriate. I was wondering if this could be done in a simpler way.

It's used by calling `format_string_number("123456789")` and prints 123,456,789.

```
def format_string_number(st):
    inputVal = list(st)
    inputVal.reverse()
    returnVal = []

    for index, value in enumerate(inputVal):
        returnVal.insert(0,value)
        if (index+1) %3 == 0:
            returnVal.insert(0,",")

    if returnVal[0] == ",":
        returnVal.pop(0)

    print("".join(returnVal))
```

Comment: I don't know enough python to tell you whether directly dealing with strings would be possible and faster... However, your condition against the index could be written `index % 3 == 2` and you'd avoid a `+1` on each iteration.

Comment: Are you looking for a better way to do it manually, or would `format(123456789, ",")` suffice?

Comment: To build off the approach suggested by @DSM : `format(int("123456789"), ",")`

Answer (score 11):

A few comments:

1. It seems odd to write a function for formatting a number that takes a string as an argument;
2. Your function doesn't currently deal with `float` numbers correctly (and, as it takes a string argument, you can't easily check `isinstance(arg, int)`);
3. Your function `print`s the output rather than `return`ing it, severely limiting its usefulness; and
4. You aren't compliant with the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Also, as pointed out in the comments, this is handled by `format` already, and can be used in `str.format` too:

```
>>> "Number: {:,}".format(123456.789)
'Number: 123,456.789'
```

Comment: using `,` is not locale aware

Comment: @user5359531 true! But nor was the original, and that requirement is not in the title or description.

Comment: I've made a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014310/locale-aware-method-to-print-large-number-with-commas-and-decimals) to address that, perhaps you could check it out.